# How to import this csv to R

Tags: r, csv, dataframe

I have no idea how to import this dataset into R. I tried the read.csv function in many different variations by changing the arguments, but all I get is a dataframe with 63 observations of 1 variable. There should be a lot more variables.
Please help me

Comment: What exactly have you tried? Take a look again at [ask]

Comment: Try with `df1 <- read.csv(file.choose(), quote = "", fill = TRUE, skip = 1, header = FALSE)` and then get the headerr line with `h1 <- readLines(file.choose(), n = 1); library(stringr); h2 <- str_extract_all(lines, "\\w+")[[1]]; names(df1) <- head(h2, length(df1))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First download the file into `L`.  Then remove the double quotes at the beginning of each line and replace each semicolon possibly preceded with a double quote with a newline. Next replace each occurrence of two double quotes in a row with one double quote.  Now read that with `read.csv`.

```
u <- "https://www.dropbox.com/sh/273oj4ah8c4wu98/AACuIQDpIEfrqfVvJWu-mTD1a/associativePersonality.csv?dl=1"
L <- readLines(u)
L2 <- gsub('^"', "", L)
L3 <- gsub('"?;', '\n', L2)
L4 <- gsub('""', '"', L3)
d <- read.csv(text = L4, as.is = TRUE, check.names = FALSE)
```